# What powershell commands are needed to add a group A from domain A as member of group B in domain B?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, cross-domain, group-membership

I want to be able to add Group A from forest A as a member of Group B in forest B. In both forests I have credentials with the Domain Administrator permissions. I have tried several things but it does not work cross-forest and I have tried several commands googled on the internet without any result so far.

I have tried several scripts but every time the object Group A from forest A could not be found when I run it from Forest B. When I use MMC Users and Computers on a domain controller of forest B I can select forest A and browse throught Active Directory without any restrictions.

Comment: Edit your question and include the things you have tried so far -- it's always best to include any code you have even if it doesn't work :)

Comment: Have you verified the security group scopes are correct for this situation? For example, have you verified that group B is a domain local or universal group and group A is a global group? If group B is a global group, you cannot add objects from another domain to it.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the `-Server` parameter to tell it the DNS name of the foreign domain:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity groupname -Members (Get-ADUser user -Server foreign.domain.com)
```

AD Users and Computers is intelligent enough to look at the trusts of the current domain to find the name of the foreign domain, but the PowerShell cmdlets are not.

Comment: When I execute following command:
import-module activedirectory
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity RGU000638 -MEMBER (Get-ADGroup GL001084 -Server INTERNAL.ZONE)

Comment: You need to use `-Members`, not `-Member`. You need the "s" on the end. PowerShell will let you use partial names for parameters, but only if they are unique. `Add-ADGroupMember` has another parameter called `-MemberTimeToLive`, so if you only use `-Member` it doesn't know if you mean `-Members` or `-MemberTimeToLive`.